# My transaction not successfully sent

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

1QEu9KydPdKxAQFcJKxzwFJYcrsSZdT6Zr

Hello support I made this Transaction since 10th November 2017 and since then the transaction has remained unconfirmed. I paid the required transfer fee but don't know what's wrong. Please I need you help

Comment: Just wait: https://blockchain.info/en/unconfirmed-transactions

Comment: Those are new transactions coming in, mine is over 48 hours now